# What machine element can we estimate a bicycle rim to be?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-mechanics

In mechanical terms, what machine element can we consider a bicycle rim to be?
Like can we design it based on the assumption that it is a curved beam/ a hoop?

Comment: I don't think this is a question about physics, because physics has no notion of "machine element."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mechanical engineering world, it is modeled as a *hoop*. There is a set of equations and analytical tools that deal with *hoop stresses* which have been applied to spoked wheels, and a large body of literature exists on them. In particular, see the papers by Jobst Brandt.